# Azure-SSIS IR deployment: the target server version of your project is unsupported

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

When deploying a SSIS package in SSISDB to be runned on Azure Data Factory I am receiving this error

> the target server version of your project (SQL Server 2019) is unsupported on Azure-SSIS IR that currently supports SQL Server 2017. Please switch the target version of your project to SQL Server 2017 using the latest SSDT

however my project is already targeting SQL Server 2017

[image]

[image]

do you know what's missing?

Comment: (1) What is your Visual Studio version? (2) Did you do a Build for the SSIS project in question?

Comment: (1)Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.4 (2) the project builds succesfully

Comment: It is a good idea to update VS2019 to v.16.11.2 and SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension to v.3.15

Comment: I'll do it and come back, thanks for the hints

Comment: After upgrading VS, SQL SISP extension and SSMS to the latest available version I constantly receive an Execution Timeout Expired exception while deploying for the first time on a catalog folder, when I try again on the same folder from now on the deployment process stops with a generic error ([Failed to deploy the project. Try again later. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) 27118]

Comment: I have found that for the last error [Failed to deploy the project. Try again later. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) 27118] to fix it is enough to delete the entry on SSISDB.internal.project related to the project that was not deployed due to timeout (source: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/working-around-failed-to-deploy-the-project-try-again-later-microsoft-sql-server-error-27118-in-ssis-deployment), so that the error I am having now is only the first one about timeout. Is there a way to increase the timeout on sql server side?

Comment: @Zeta - You can increase the timeout  on SQL using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2878/How-to-Increase-the-MS-SQL-Remote-Query-Timeout.html)